# Python reference for hasattr() choices to identify types

Tags: python, reference, hasattr

Is there a good one-stop-shop Python reference for choosing attributes to use with hasattr() to identify types.

For example, the following is for a sequence which is not a string:

```py
def is_sequence(arg):
    return (not hasattr(arg, "strip") and
            hasattr(arg, "__getitem__") or
            hasattr(arg, "__iter__"))
```

It would be nice to have a solid reference for choosing the best patterns quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [virtual subclasses](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-abstract-base-class) that have already been written for you in the [collections module](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) ([collections.abc](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.abc.html) in Python 3.3).

To check if something is a non-string sequence, use

```
from collections import Sequence    # collections.abc in Python 3.3
isinstance(arg, Sequence) and not isinstance(arg, basestring)    # str in Python 3
```

Comment: I was using isinstance regularly but I continued to read it is more "Pythonic" to use hasattr so that we don't unnecessarily exclude objects that have the proper methods and would otherwise work.

Comment: @majgis -- Really, the you can just `try` to use the object, and if you get an `AttributeError`, apparently it didn't work.  You *could* check if the object has all of the attributes that you're going to use using `hasattr`, however, `isinstance` exists for those rare times when you want to make sure you're working with a list and not something else.  Don't be afraid to use `isinstance` if you *need* a specific type.  However, you don't usually *need* a specific type, and you rarely need to check ahead of time because of `try`/`except`

Comment: @majgis that advice predates the existence of virtual subclasses.  Note that the *most* Pythonic code still tends to use `try`/`except`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the appropriate [abstract base class](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html):

```
import collections
isinstance([], collections.Sequence) # ==> true
```